# SUBSTRING_INDEX in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to run a query in RoR that would have the same results as the following?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(notes, ',' , 1) AS notes FROM <table> WHERE event = 'Bar'
```

I've tried and tried but the substring_index part seems to not be friendly with the find_by_sql function.

**Update** This is a more accurate portrayal of the query I am attempting to make.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(notes, ',', 1) notes, COUNT(*) cnt FROM <table> WHERE event = 'Foo' GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(notes, ',', 1) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

I'm close with this call:

```
Foo.where("event = 'Foo'").group('notes').order('count_all').count()
```

But it's obviously not quite right.

Comment: Why don't you use Ruby to get the substring?

Comment: Because what I'm trying to do is actually group the results by that value as well. I just simplified the example. I'll update it with the more complex query so you can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Foo.select("SUBSTRING_INDEX(notes, ',', 1) AS notes, COUNT(*) AS cnt").
where(:event => "Foo").group('notes').order('cnt DESC')
```

Comment: That's the closest I've seen it yet! Unfortunately the count is not getting displayed. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, it seems like the issue is you cant do AS and change the name to something else. For instance, when I changed notes to AS notestwo it displays nothing.